# Using Wicked with Devise for a sign up wizard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, wizard

I am using devise with wicked to create a sign up wizard, but I am unsure about a problem I am having creating profiles. After a user provides their email & password they are forwarded to a step to create a profile based on whether they have specified they are a shipper or carrier. However I am unsure what the code should be in the controller and the forms to generically create a profile. Here is the code I have for the application:

The steps controller:

```
class UserStepsController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard
  steps :carrier_profile, :shipper_profile


 def create
   @user = User.last
   case step
   when :carrier_profile
     @profile = CarrierProfile.create!(:dot => params[:dot])
     if @profile.save
        render_wizard @user
     else
        flash[:alert] = "Record not saved"
     end
   when :shipper_profile
     @profile = ShipperProfile.create!(params[:shipper_profile)
     if @profile.save
        render_wizard @user
     else
        flash[:alert] = "Record not saved"
     end
   end
 end
```

end
      end

```
  def show
    @user = User.last
    @carrier_profile = CarrierProfile.new
    @shipper_profile = ShipperProfile.new
    case step
    when :carrier_profile
      skip_step if @user.shipper?
    when :shipper_profile
      skip_step if @user.carrier?
    end
    render_wizard
  end
end
```

The form for a carrier profile:

```
<% form_for @carrier_profile , url: wizard_path, method: :post do |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :dot, "Please enter your DOT Number:" %>
    <%= f.text_field :dot %>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit "Next Step", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The form for a shipper profile:

```
<% form_for @shipper_profile , url: wizard_path, method: :post do |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :company_name, "What is your company name?" %>
    <%= f.text_field :company_name %>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit "Next Step", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :carrier_profile
  has_one :shipper_profile
end
```

How would I be able to write a generic new and create method to handle creating both profiles? With the current code it is stating that the user_steps controller has no POST method, although if I run rake routes I find that this is untrue.

Answer (score 3):

## Add a step :profile_select to find which profile should be created

```
class UserStepsController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard
  steps :profile_select, :carrier_profile, :shipper_profile

  def update
    @user = current_user
    case step
    when :profile_select
      if params[:user][:profile_type] == 'carrier'
        @profile = current_user.carrier_profile.build 
      else
        @profile = current_user.shipper_profile.build 
      end
    when :carrier_profile
      current_user.carrier_profile.update_attributes(params[:carrier_profile])
      when :shipper_profile
      current_user.shipper_profile.update_attributes(params[:shipper_profile])
    end
    render_wizard @user
  end

  def show
    @user = current_user
    case step
    when :carrier_profile
      skip_step if @user.shipper?
    when :shipper_profile
      skip_step if @user.carrier?
    end
    render_wizard
  end
end
```

## views/user_steps/profile_select.html.erb:

## Note: method :put so that update gets called for all steps

```
<%= form_for current_user, url: wizard_path, method: :put do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :profile_type %>
  <%= f.text_field :profile_type %>
  <%= f.submit "Next Step", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

## views/user_steps/carrier_profile.html.erb:

```
<% form_for @profile, url: wizard_path, method: :put do |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :dot, "Please enter your DOT Number:" %>
    <%= f.text_field :dot %>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit "Next Step", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

## views/user_steps/shipper_profile.html.erb:

```
<% form_for @profile, url: wizard_path, method: :put do |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :company_name, "What is your company name?" %>
    <%= f.text_field :company_name %>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit "Next Step", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The profiles are their own separate objects that belong to user, not a field that can be updated from the user object. So entering in form_for "@user" will not work with an update action they must be created. I am going to need to do something like "@carrier_profile" or "@shipper_profile". Since I am using devise's confirmable module I don't have access to the current_user method since they are not logged into the session. I will eventually have to do something like User.find_by_email("email") but for development purposes this works right now.

Comment: Yes, if you have a two different profile objects that you want to update depending on the type of profile, the form is for "@carrier_profile" or "@shipper_profile". You can just add a step prior to showing forms and create this profile objects in show based on what profile the user belongs to.

Comment: I want to be able to create a profile after I create a user, not update a profile.

Comment: The controller's :create and :update method are not related with profile model's :create and :update. The idea here is that the wizard controller represents a psuedo-model object that gets updated by the choices selected by the user and shows different options to the user accordingly. So, :show and :update methods are all you need.